# Changing document class causes some thicker lines in tables

Tags: tables

I have a table in a paper that when I change its document class, some of its tables shows unwanted thicker lines like this:

[image]

Here is my preamble of my paper and one table's code:

```
%Initial rules
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,5p,preprint]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{array}
% Start of 'ignore natbib' hack
\let\bibhang\relax
\let\citename\relax
\let\bibfont\relax
\let\Citeauthor\relax
\expandafter\let\csname ver@natbib.sty\endcsname\relax
% End of 'ignore natbib' hack

% Start of c@uthor conflict resolution
\makeatletter
\let\c@author\relax
\makeatother
% End of c@uthor conflict resolution

\usepackage[english]{babel}% Recommended
\usepackage{csquotes}% Recommended

\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\overfullrule=1mm
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\begin{document}
\begin{sloppypar}
\begin{frontmatter}

\title{My Title}

% Body of paper

% Table definition
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{Specification of test data sets in selected seasons}
\label{table-test}
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{
    \begin{tabular}{|m{0.31\columnwidth}|m{0.23\columnwidth}|
                    m{0.23\columnwidth}|m{0.23\columnwidth}|}
    \hline
                       & \textbf{Number of test records} & \textbf{WINS} & \textbf{LOSSES} \\ \hline
    \textbf{2005-2006} & 200       & 79            & 121             \\ \hline
    \textbf{2015-2016} & 200       & 80            & 120             \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
```

It works nice. But when I change the initial rules of the document, there will be an unwanted thicker line in the table as shown above.

```
% **Start of changed part of initial rules**
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
%
\documentclass{svjour3}                     
%
\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
%
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{blindtext}

% **End of changed part of initial rules, Other parts of the document without any change**

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{array}

% Start of 'ignore natbib' hack
\let\bibhang\relax
\let\citename\relax
\let\bibfont\relax
\let\Citeauthor\relax
\expandafter\let\csname ver@natbib.sty\endcsname\relax
% End of 'ignore natbib' hack

% Start of c@uthor conflict resolution
\makeatletter
\let\c@author\relax
\makeatother
% End of c@uthor conflict resolution

\usepackage[english]{babel}% Recommended
\usepackage{csquotes}% Recommended

\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\overfullrule=1mm
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\journalname{SN Computer Science}
\begin{document}
\begin{sloppypar}
\begin{frontmatter}

\title{My Title}

% Body of paper

% Table definition
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{Specification of test data sets in selected seasons}
\label{table-test}
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{
    \begin{tabular}{|m{0.31\columnwidth}|m{0.23\columnwidth}|
                    m{0.23\columnwidth}|m{0.23\columnwidth}|}
    \hline
                       & \textbf{Number of test records} & \textbf{WINS} & \textbf{LOSSES} \\ \hline
    \textbf{2005-2006} & 200       & 79            & 121             \\ \hline
    \textbf{2015-2016} & 200       & 80            & 120             \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is as a result of

```
\overfullrule=1mm
```

in the preamble. It will set a thick (`1mm`) rule for every overfull box. See [Is it possible to make LaTeX mark overfull boxes in the output?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/75140/5764) Since the `LOSSES` column is set as an `m`-column (a fixed-width `p`-column with vertically-centred content) it has a fixed width. `LOSSES` is too wide for the `.23\columnwidth` column width, thereby causing the vertical bar being drawn.

Remove the `\overfullrule` adjustment or use an adjustable column specification (like `l`, or `c`, or `r`).